# Creating a custom image using python Azure SDK in DevTestLabs

Tags: python, azure, azure-devtest-labs

I am trying to create a custom image from a VHD which I uploaded to the devtest lab.

I am using the following code to do that:

```
from azure.mgmt.storage import StorageManagementClient
....
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials( client_id = '##', tenant = '##', secret = "##")
resource_client = DevTestLabsClient(credentials, subscriptID)

....
custom_image_properties = CustomImagePropertiesCustom(CustomImageOsType.windows, config.CustomImage.Name, True)
custom_image = CustomImage(vhd = custom_image_properties)
resource_client.custom_images.create_or_update(rgName,labName, imageName, custom_image)
```

It throws me the following error :
Failed to parse URI named ImageName with value of '##customImageName##'.

Let me know what I am doing wrong? And where am I suppossed to enter the path to the VHD in the API. I cannot find any argument which takes the path!

Comment: Any progress? Does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

> It throws me the following error : Failed to parse URI named ImageName
>   with value of '##customImageName##'.

According to the error message, it seems the `imagename` value is a URI.

The image name should be a string.

```
create_or_update(resource_group_name, lab_name, name, custom_image, custom_headers=None, raw=False, **operation_config)


Parameters: 
resource_group_name (str) – The name of the resource group.
lab_name (str) – The name of the lab.
name (str) – The name of the custom image.
```

More information please refer to this [link](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.mgmt.devtestlabs.operations.html?highlight=custom%20images#azure.mgmt.devtestlabs.operations.CustomImagesOperations.create_or_update).

---

By the way, to troubleshoot this issue more efficiency， could you please post your whole script:)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create `custom image` with the code you offered.

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.devtestlabs import DevTestLabsClient
from azure.mgmt.devtestlabs.models.custom_image_properties_custom import CustomImagePropertiesCustom
from azure.mgmt.devtestlabs.models.custom_image import CustomImage
from azure.mgmt.devtestlabs.models.dev_test_labs_client_enums import CustomImageOsType

client_id = <your client id>
tenant = <your tenant id>
secret = <your secret id>
subscriptID = <your subcript id>
imageName='jaygong.vhd'
name=<your custom image name as you want>
rgName = <your resource name>
labName = <your lab name>

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id=client_id, tenant=tenant , secret=secret)
resource_client = DevTestLabsClient(credentials, subscriptID)
custom_image_properties = CustomImagePropertiesCustom(CustomImageOsType.windows, imageName, True)
custom_image = CustomImage(vhd = custom_image_properties)
resource_client.custom_images.create_or_update(rgName,labName, name, custom_image)
```

then I reproduction your issue.

```
E:\Python27\python.exe E:/PythonWorkSpace/CreateVM/Create.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/PythonWorkSpace/CreateVM/Create.py", line 19, in <module>
    resource_client.custom_images.create_or_update(rgName,labName, imageName, custom_image)
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\azure\mgmt\devtestlabs\operations\custom_images_operations.py", line 293, in create_or_update
    get_long_running_status, long_running_operation_timeout)
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\msrestazure\azure_operation.py", line 350, in __init__
    raise CloudError(self._response)
msrestazure.azure_exceptions.CloudError: Azure Error: InvalidUrlProvided
Message: Failed to parse URI named ImageName with value of 'aaa'.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

After researching,I found that the `imageName` parameter above not just your `VHD` name,it supposed to be the `complete url` of your `VHD` file in your storage name.
It looks like :

```
https://<your storage account>.blob.core.windows.net/<your container name>/<your vhd file name>
```

I changed the value of the `imageName` then created custom image successfully.

[image]

Hope it helps you.Any concern,please feel free to let me kown.